# android reach next and previous item of listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a *listView* that filled by custom Adapter and listed some sounds from external storage.
when user click on each item of *listView* a custom *alerDialog* pop-up and it has play, next and previous *buttons*.
The problem is I have no idea how to reach information of next and previous sound in *listView* to play them in this *alertDialog* without closing it?(in other words I want to reach information of my *listView* from another class(*alertDialog*)) Thanks for help.

Comment: maybe you could send the data that you use in your custom adapter to the alertDialog. And the position of the current sound that you want to listen to.

Comment: You must have the data backing the Adapter.  Why not use that?

Comment: @VictorPettengillFernandes Thanks for your response. I tried to use position but when I have an alertDialog in screen and use position to call next sound, I'll have a new alertDialog on my old one. and so on.I can't close the old alertDialog. so I thought maybe I should somehow reach information of next and previous sounds.

Comment: @RyanM Thanks for your response. I didn't understand what you mean. Can you explain it?

Comment: When you create the AlertDialog, you have a reference to the data.  Why not just use that within the AlertDialog?

Comment: @RyanM I defined ListView's position public static and use it within the AlertDialog but the problem is when I call a new AlertDilaog the old one is still on the screen and I can't (or don't know how to) close it.